# How to align two views in Android?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity

**I have two views within Linear layout. One view is TextView and another one is EditText. I want aligned both of them. Here is the screenshot and code.**

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="80dp"
    android:background="#ccc"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_weight="1">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="20dp"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:text="S1"
        android:background="#110faa">

    </TextView>

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:background="#102df2"
        android:inputType="numberDecimal"
        android:importantForAutofill="no">

    </EditText>

</LinearLayout>
```

**This is what it looks right now i don't want that top spacing on S1 text view.**

Here is the screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Add `android:baselineAligned="false"` to the opening `<LinearLayout>` tag.

Comment: You should be using constraint layout it is much more performant...if your layout gets complicated linear layout is going to be really hard to maintain

Comment: `ConstraintLayout` is certainly _not_ more performant than `LinearLayout`. Please stop suggesting `ConstraintLayout` for everything. It's not meant to replace every `ViewGroup` in every situation.

Comment: Thanks Mike M. your answer was useful. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `android:layout_weight` to divided width of LinearLayout and
`android:baselineAligned="false"` for top spacing

```
 <LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:background="#ccc"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_weight="5"
        android:baselineAligned="false">
    
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="20dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#110faa"
            android:text="S1">
    
        </TextView>
    
        <EditText
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="20dp"
            android:layout_weight="4"
            android:background="#102df2"
            android:importantForAutofill="no"
            android:inputType="numberDecimal"></EditText>
    
    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: hello elham :), can you please please help me with this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62887229/cant-zoom-the-webview-under-swipe-to-refresh/62887494#62887494

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this :

```
      <LinearLayout
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="80dp"
             android:background="#ccc"
             android:orientation="horizontal"
             android:gravity="center_vertical">

        <TextView
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
             android:layout_height="match_parent"
             android:gravity="center"
             android:text="S1"
             android:background="#110faa">
        </TextView>

        <EditText
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:gravity="center_vertical"
              android:background="#102df2"
              android:inputType="numberDecimal"
              android:importantForAutofill="no"/>

       </LinearLayout>
```