# Android TextView clips text when setting maxlines="1" with gravity="center" and ellipsize="end"

Tags: android, textview, gravity, ellipsize, android-singleline

When using `maxLines="1"` in combination with `gravity="center"` and `ellipsize="end"`, the text gets clipped from the beginning.

```xml
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        style="@style/TextAppearance.MaterialComponents.Body1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:text="Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s" />

</LinearLayout>
```

[image]

The issue gets resolved if `maxLines="1"` is changed to `singleLine="true"`, but it's a [deprecated attribute](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html#singleLine).

Comment: This issue only happens when the style of `TextView` is set to `@style/TextAppearance.MaterialComponents...`

Answer (score 4):

It seems that `TextAppearance.MaterialComponents.Body…` sets `android:letterSpacing` to something more than zero. When this attribute is set to `android:letterSpacing="0.0"` the issue gets resolved.

Comment: hello reza :), can you help me with this please? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62887229/cant-zoom-the-webview-under-swipe-to-refresh/62887494